# Cant pass List To Custom View

Tags: android

Now I have this Custom View and I want to pass data from activity to this layout

```
public class ImageViewing extends LinearLayout {
    ArrayList<String> urlsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ImageViewing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }

    public ImageViewing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public ImageViewing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getUrlsArrayList() {
        return urlsArrayList;
    }

    public void setUrlsArrayList(ArrayList<String> urlsArrayList) {
//        this.urlsArrayList.clear();
//        this.urlsArrayList.addAll(urlsArrayList);
        this.urlsArrayList   = urlsArrayList;
        invalidate();

    }

    private void init() {
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        if (urlsArrayList != null) {
            int size = urlsArrayList.size();
            AppLogger.log("Size",""+size);
            switch (size) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    onePictureView();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    twoPictureView();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    threePictureView();

                    break;
                case 4:
                    fourPictureView();
                    break;
                default:
                    moreThanFourPictureView(size);
                    break;

            }
        } else {
        }
        invalidate();

    }}
```

and I want to pass Array List put list Is Always 0 size

I added it As view Like this

```
<com.tmoo7.carmasrclub.cutomView.ImageViewing
    android:id="@+id/viewImagesLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

then In My Activity

```
  viewImagesLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewImagesLayout);
viewImagesLayout.setUrlsArrayList(model.getPostImageUrl());
```

can Any One help me and tell me what is wrong please
can Any One help me and tell me what is wrong please
can Any One help me and tell me what is wrong please

Comment: create your view programmaticaly instead of xml and pass your list in constructor of your view.

Comment: ok I will do this

Comment: @MikeM. when I use this In Adapter It`s Repeating On scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the switch case

```
        switch (size) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                onePictureView();
                break;
            case 2:
                twoPictureView();
                break;
            case 3:
                threePictureView();

                break;
            case 4:
                fourPictureView();
                break;
            default:
                moreThanFourPictureView(size);
                break;

        }
```

into your "setUrlsArryList" method instead

```
public void setUrlsArrayList(ArrayList<String> urlsArrayList) {
    this.urlsArrayList   = urlsArrayList;
    // here
    invalidate();
    }
```

assuming that your onePictureView(), twoPictureView(), threePictureView() methods really change your view's appearance

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the order your methods chain up :
- constructor()
- init() { urlsArrayList = null }
- setUrlsArrayList(urlsArrayList)
-> ***setUrlsArrayList()*** is called after ***init()***

If you want your methods to chain up in the right order you must call your "init()" in this lifecycle callback "onAttachedToWindow()"

```
public class ImageViewing extends LinearLayout {

   public ImageViewing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs)
   }

   private void init() {...}

   public void setUrlsArrayList(ArrayList<String> urlsArrayList) {...}

   @Override
   protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
      init()
   }
}
```

Comment: onAttachedToWindow work Fine   But when Use It In Recycler view

at evey scrolling it`s call Init() again

Comment: Hi Elsunhoty, can you post your code. I need more informations to debug your problem.